# Setting Title of UIbuttons in loop in swift

Tags: ios, collections, swift, uibutton

I have made a collection of UIButtons like this

```
@IBOutlet var btnChannle1:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle2:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle3:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle4:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle5:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle6:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle7:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var btnChannle8:UIButton!
@IBOutlet var channlesCollection:Array<UIView>!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle1)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle2)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle3)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle4)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle5)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle6)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle7)
    channlesCollection.append(btnChannle8)
}
```

now I want to traverse the collection above and want some thing like this

```
for item in channlesCollection{
        // Set Button Text Line to 2
        // Set Button Text Like this in two line
        /*

        01
        CNN

        02
        BBC

        03
        PTV ...

                */

    }
```

but when Im trying like this.

```
for item in channlesCollection{
        item.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
```

error raised UIView does not have member named setTitle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type-cast item as `UIButton`. Here is the code:

```
for item in  channlesCollection{
   var button:UIButton = item as UIButton
   button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are having array of `UIView` and they indeed don't having a `setTitle` method. Either make your collection of type `UIButton`. Or cast your current collection items to buttons:

```
for item in channlesCollection {
    if var button = item as? UIButton {
        button.setTitle("Test", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`UIView` does not have a member function `setTitle`, but `UIButton` has, which is probably what you want.

You have declared your `channlesCollection` as array of `UIView`, why not as array of `UIButton`?

```
var channlesCollection: [UIButton]!
```

Comment: I tries this but this error and crash NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type